# How can I configure the RFM95 LoRa module to emit packets at only 'one' particular frequency?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, wireless, frequency

I have created a LoRa gateway using a Pi3; I have used a RFM95 module for it. So, it is a single channel gateway, and I'm operating it at 868.1Mhz. But my LoRa node(also a RFM95, on an Arduino Uno), whenever transmits data, does so on various frequencies at random, and there seems to be no pattern to it. Hence a lot of data gets lost. How can i transmit data on a particular frequency only?